# Which airlines ban the use of Knee Defenders during flight?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, gear, seating

I read that some airlines such as [United Airlines](http://www.theguardian.com/business/2014/aug/26/plane-diverted-as-passengers-fight-over-seat-reclining) ban the use of [Knee Defenders](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/ampp3d/knee-defenders-what-really-necessary-4108447) during flight. Is there any comprehensive list of airlines that ban the use of Knee Defenders during flight (or conversely a list of airlines that do not ban them)?

Comment: I'm curious if users of Knee Defenders recline their own seats.

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm sure they have a 'Knee Defendant Honor Code'.

Comment: @a20 egocentric jerks have an honour code? Unless it is "I do what I like, others be darned" of course. Most people who go out of their way to control the behaviour of others (including spending good money on things like this) are people who don't give a darn about other people, and will throw their seats back the moment the seatbelt sign goes off and not put them back up until they're told to in person by a flight attendant (and then complain about it).

Comment: I'm sure it was tongue-in-cheek...

Comment: The picture with the man with his knees up is a joke and misrepresents. I'm tall and I put my feet under the seat in front of me. Why promote a false image that isn't accurate. put your feet under the seat in front of you dummy!

Comment: Maybe tall people should have preemptive rights to the front end row seats? The airlines configure planes for mini people in a land of many giants, setting the stage for crushed people in coach. Maybe they should sedate everyone and pack them like spoons. The poor person who pays for a fully functioning seat and discovers a giant behind them is a secondary victim of the airlines 'one size fits all in coach' mantra. Throwing water is no solution.

Comment: I wonder why **Cathay Pacific** got rid of its **fixed-back seats**. That was **a good compromise** for both the reclining person and the person behind.

Comment: @gparyani CX's shell seats were widely derided as exceptionally uncomfortable. They were removed by popular demand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would appear not, but there's nothing stopping us from creating one.  People can edit the answer as we find more.

**Airlines that ban the Knee Defender**

- Air Canada [source](http://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/knee-defender-a-no-fly-for-canadian-airlines-1.1977816)
- American Airlines [source](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/travel/travel-news/is-this-the-most-obnoxious-invention-in-air-travel/article571245/)
- Continental Airlines [source](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/travel/travel-news/is-this-the-most-obnoxious-invention-in-air-travel/article571245/)
- Delta Airlines [source](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-08-26/legroom-gadget-maker-sees-sales-jump-after-air-rage-case.html)
- Jetstar [source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2735365/Qantas-Virgin-warn-passengers-using-Knee-Defenders-bad-smoking-using-illegal-drugs-planes-sales-banned-devices-soar-US-fight-incident.html)
- Qantas [source](http://www.ausbt.com.au/qantas-virgin-australia-ban-knee-defender)
- Southwest Airlines [source](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-08-26/legroom-gadget-maker-sees-sales-jump-after-air-rage-case.html)
- United Airlines [source](http://www.straitstimes.com/news/singapore/more-singapore-stories/story/6-things-about-the-knee-defender-20140827)
- Jetstar [source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2735365/Qantas-Virgin-warn-passengers-using-Knee-Defenders-bad-smoking-using-illegal-drugs-planes-sales-banned-devices-soar-US-fight-incident.html)
- Virgin Australia [source 1](http://www.ausbt.com.au/qantas-virgin-australia-ban-knee-defender) ; [source 2](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2735365/Qantas-Virgin-warn-passengers-using-Knee-Defenders-bad-smoking-using-illegal-drugs-planes-sales-banned-devices-soar-US-fight-incident.html)
- WestJet [source](http://www.ctvnews.ca/canada/knee-defender-a-no-fly-for-canadian-airlines-1.1977816)

**Airlines that discourage but don't ban the Knee Defender**

- British Airways [source](http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?news_id=99176&c=setreg&region=4)
- JetBlue Airways [source](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-08-26/legroom-gadget-maker-sees-sales-jump-after-air-rage-case.html)

**Airlines that allow the Knee Defender**

- EasyJet [source](http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?news_id=99176&c=setreg&region=4)
- Virgin Atlantic [source](http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?news_id=99176&c=setreg&region=4)

**Airlines with seats that do not recline**

- Allegiant Air [source](http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2014/08/29/legroom-wars-calls-for-upright-seats/)
- Spirit [source](http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2014/08/29/legroom-wars-calls-for-upright-seats/)
- Ryanair [source](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/3489761.stm)

Comment: That source about some British airlines supposedly allowing Knee Defender is *really* dubious...

Comment: @it's really old, but it's a source.   If someone has something more up to date, they can update it...

Comment: On two low-fare US Airlines, Spirit and Allegiant, the seats do not recline so Knee Defender is superfluous.

Comment: I believe Cathay Pacific used to obviate the need for one, mainly due to its fixed-back seats (non-reclining faux-recline), but I don't know what they do now that they've gotten rid of them. Speaking of which, what's Emirates' policy on them?

Comment: For reasons given in the other answer, the contents of this one is superfluous.

Answer (score 29):

**Such a list would not be meaningful.**  All airlines have wide rules to prohibit "tampering" with seats, with Knee Defenders or otherwise; you can [improvise one with a well-sized bottle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/20186/1893), after all.  Those that point out the Knee Defender as banned are only making it explicit that this specific device is not allowed.

More to the point, if the passenger unable to recline complains, the flight attendants *will* insist that you stop using it.

Comment: some have specifically banned said device, from the articles I was reading this morning - [for example](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/travel/travel-news/is-this-the-most-obnoxious-invention-in-air-travel/article571245/).

Comment: Yes, but the point I'm trying to make is that "not banned" does not equal "allowed".

Comment: hmm, yeah that's a valid point.  Doesn't stop us making a list though :)

Comment: Could the flight attendants ban reclining as well, if the crushed passenger complains?

Comment: No.  Everybody has the right to recline and the responsibility to accept getting reclined on.  If you don't like this, pay for a bigger seat.  See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20171/how-to-prevent-the-passenger-in-front-of-you-from-reclining-without-notice

Comment: I don’t mind getting reclined on, but the person in front is going to have to accept that they’re not going to be able to recline very far as my thighs are long enough that my knees act as their own Knee Defenders in most economy seats.

Comment: @Robin There is always a nice solution of asking a person in front not to do this.

Comment: @Karlson sadly in today's world nice solutions and common decency are fading fast in place of hard bans and lawsuits .. real pity.

Comment: @a20 I don't think it's "common decency" to comply with someone's request not to recline one's seat. Nobody likes being reclined on and everyone knows this, so why would someone change their behavior because you asked them not to recline their seat?

Comment: @JLRishe hmm I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In any case, what I meant was, if the "recliner" thought about the person behind and just checked first, or if the person behind asked the other one to give notice before reclining .. and both were nice and gentlemanly about the whole thing, that would be "common decency" in my book. So I meant that there's less of that kind of thoughtfulness and courtesy nowadays.

Comment: @a20 What I mean is that it would be a pointless and empty gesture because nobody likes it when the person in front of them reclines and everybody knows that. The unwritten rule is that if someone wants to recline, they recline. Asking for permission is pointless. Also, I've been flying economy class for about 30 years and I've never had someone ask me for permission to recline their seat, so I'm not sure what you mean about there being less thoughtfulness and courtesy "nowadays". Sounds to me like misplaced nostalgia for the "good old days".

Comment: @JLRishe 'misplaced nostalgia for the "good old days"' hahah .. you're probably right ;)